# typescript/JS module pattern. splitting into multiple files

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please see the [code below](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20AAA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20module%20user%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20var%20am%20%20=%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A//1.%0D%0Amodule%20AAA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20module%20user%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20am%5B%27x%27%5D=%20%27y%27;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A//2.%0D%0Amodule%20AAA%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20module%20user%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20user.am%5B%27x%27%5D=%20%27y%27;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

```
module AAA {
    export module user {
         export var am  = {}
    }
}

//1.
module AAA {
    export module user {
       am['x']= 'y';
    }
}

//2.
module AAA {
    export module user {
       user.am['x']= 'y';
    }
}
```

I am trying to split a module into two (or more) files. first (1.) form doesn't work, as the code generated sometimes (couldn't produce in playground) looks like (note the underscore)

```
var AAA;
(function (AAA) {
    (function (_user) {
        AAA._user.am['x'] = 'y';
    })(AAA.user || (AAA.user = {}));
    var user = AAA.user;
})(AAA || (AAA = {}));
```

but, second (2.) form works fine and I get intellisense for variable `am`. is this a reliable way, if I guarantee the order of files referenced? or do I need to refer from the root like, `AAA.user.am['x']= 'y';`  or a better way?

Also, in the generated code, there are two variable declaration `var AAA;`. Would this cause any issue. If I use a minifier, can it rid of it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the 1.0RC compiler. [See this page](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2222) where you can get a hotfix tsc.js file.

Comment: it worked.. thanks. can u please answer the other qn `Also, in the generated code, there are two variable declaration var AAA;. Would this cause any issue. If I use a minifier, can it rid of it`